# List view not refreshing when item is deleted

Tags: android, listview

I Have a list view where i have loaded it with json array data. I have minus button to delete row from list. Here the problem is I am able to delete the item but list view is not getting refreshed. The list view gets refreshed once the application is closed or when I go back and navigate to that activity again.

Below is the custom adapter class code:

```
 public class AddPassengerAdapater extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

    private final JSONArray jsonArray;
   ArrayList<String> data;
    Context context;
    JSONObject json_data;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public AddPassengerAdapater(Context context, JSONArray jsonArray,ArrayList<String> data) {

        this.context = context;
        this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
        this.data = data;

        String details = SessionManager.getPreferences(context,"splitfare_consumer");
        data = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONArray jsonarray = null;
        try {
            jsonarray = new JSONArray(details);
            for (int i=0; i < jsonarray.length() ; i++){
                json_data = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                data.add(String.valueOf(json_data));

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }

    @Override public int getCount() {
        if(null==jsonArray)
            return 0;
        else
            return jsonArray.length();
    }


    @Override public JSONObject getItem(int position) {
        if(null==jsonArray) return null;
        else
            return jsonArray.optJSONObject(position);
    }

    @Override public long getItemId(int position) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = getItem(position);

        return jsonObject.optLong("id");
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final MyViewHolder mViewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addpassenger_row_layout, parent, false);
            mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        }
        else {
            mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


         json_data = getItem(position);
        try {
            String n =  json_data.getString("name");
            mViewHolder.name.setText(n);
            String nu =  json_data.getString("number");
            mViewHolder.number.setText(nu);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        mViewHolder.deletelist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            JSONArray delete_jsonarray;
            JSONObject jsonObject;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String phonenumber = mViewHolder.number.getText().toString();
                String jsonsetpreference_data = SessionManager.getPreferences(context,"splitfare_consumer");
                Log.d("jsonsetpreference_data:::::::","" +jsonsetpreference_data);
                try {
                    delete_jsonarray= new JSONArray(jsonsetpreference_data);
                    for (int i =0; i<= delete_jsonarray.length()-1 ; i++){
                        jsonObject = delete_jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String array_phonenumber = jsonObject.getString("number");
                        if (phonenumber.equals(array_phonenumber)){
                            delete_jsonarray.remove(i);
                        }
                    }
                    SessionManager.setPreferences(context,"splitfare_consumer",delete_jsonarray.toString());


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private class MyViewHolder {


        TextView name, number;
        ImageView deletelist;

        public MyViewHolder(View item) {

            name = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.consumername);
            number = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.consumer_number);
            deletelist = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.dltconsumer);

        }
    }


}

Listview activity code:

        public class AddPassengerList extends AppCompatActivity {

        @BindView(R.id.listview)
        ListView listview;

        @BindView(R.id.btn_addmore)
        CustomFontButton btn_addmore;

        @BindView(R.id.donebtn)
        CustomFontButton donebtn;

        public static final String TAG = "AddPassengerList";
        Activity activity=this;
        Context context = this;
        JSONArray js;
        AddPassengerAdapater adapter;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        String name ;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_passenger_list);
            ButterKnife.bind(this);

             /*Status bar color*/
            Window window = activity.getWindow();
            // clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            // add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            // finally change the color
            window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorAccent));

 String data = SessionManager.getPreferences(context,"splitfare_consumer");

            Log.d(TAG,""+data);

            ArrayList<String> details= new  ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                js = new JSONArray(data);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

           adapter = new AddPassengerAdapater(context,js,details);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            btn_addmore.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()){
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            btn_addmore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.addmorepassengerpressed);
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            btn_addmore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.addmorepassenger);
                            Intent i = new Intent(AddPassengerList.this,AddPassenger.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

           }

       }
```

Comment: after deleting the item, call notifyDataSetchanged() method

Comment: I did that but it didn't work for me

Comment: Are your adapter class outside your activity class ?

Comment: yes, I have separate class

Comment: Now you need to explain your code. you are passing a json array and empty data array to your constructor, then you are populating the data array with it. Then you are actually populating your listview with jsonArray and not using data array anywhere and then when you are deleting an object you are deleting form another array delete_array. How is this ever going to work can you please explain what all arrays are these.

Comment: Also what does delete_array has, object to be deleted or object that is already deleted?

Comment: In delete_json array first I am getting the value from shared preference and deleting the object from it updating the array list.

Comment: can you please suggest me where I have went wrong. Please edit my code

Comment: I cannnot edit the whole code as its changes at a lot of level. Basically you should have only 1 arraylist in your adapater that should be used throughout. You should add to it, show data from it and delete data also from the same array. right now you are doing things from 3 different arrays and hence your code will not work. Change your code to use only 1 array and then let us know if it still doesn't work

Comment: ok, I will change

Comment: @Kapsym Thanks a lot. It works

Comment: Great. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Recall your adapter again after delete item...

```
 mViewHolder.deletelist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        JSONArray delete_jsonarray;
        JSONObject jsonObject;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String phonenumber = mViewHolder.number.getText().toString();
            String jsonsetpreference_data = SessionManager.getPreferences(context,"splitfare_consumer");
            Log.d("jsonsetpreference_data:::::::","" +jsonsetpreference_data);
            try {
                delete_jsonarray= new JSONArray(jsonsetpreference_data);
                for (int i =0; i<= delete_jsonarray.length()-1 ; i++){
                    jsonObject = delete_jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String array_phonenumber = jsonObject.getString("number");
                    if (phonenumber.equals(array_phonenumber)){
                        delete_jsonarray.remove(i);
                    }
                }
                SessionManager.setPreferences(context,"splitfare_consumer",delete_jsonarray.toString());


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


    });
```

Comment: can you suggest me how to do that?

Comment: just write this line after item delete code

Comment: Globally make object of adapter

Comment: @NaveenKumar `mViewHolder.deletelist.setOnClickListener` in this method after deleting the item just call `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Thnx Nilesh for improving my answer..

Comment: i added that line but still not working for me.

Comment: Where should I exactly  place this line of code.

Comment: after catch () clause ,put notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @Vishal its not working.

Comment: @VishalVaishnav it will not work like that.